# In Carrierwave how to let a user download an s3 file only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Let's say I upload a file to S3 using Carrierwave in my Rails application. I need to make sure :

- The file is hidden (The actual url to be hidden)
- Let a user download the file from a temporarily generated URL which allows only 1 download. If we retype that url it won't let the user download the file

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that the user should not be able to download the file at all after the first time, or just not through the same url?

Comment: Not through the same url

Comment: Have you consider to have a short expiration time on an authenticated url as discussed here? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/L3J8d4ZKySM Not really what you asked for, but might be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it code itself. You need to track record of downloaded file.

For this you need to create a table that hold information for user and file that already downloaded.

To hide actual s3 url, You need to first read file in your code from s3 and available that file to user with `send_data`.

```
xyz = Xyz.find(params[:id])
data = open(xyz_file_path).read
send_file data, filename: file_name_that_you_want, 
  type: file_content_type, stream: 'true', 
  :x_sendfile => true
```